# Json array and play framework 2 with Java

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0

I'm using a route to post json to my app based on Play Framework 2 :

This is the content of the route file :

```
POST    /api/localfeeds             controllers.Application.addMessage()
```

And this is my java code :

```
public static Result addMessage() {
  JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
  if(json == null) {
    return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
  } else {
        String message = json.findPath("message").getTextValue();
        String patate = json.findPath("patate").getTextValue();
        String potato = json.findPath("potato").getTextValue();
    if(message == null || patate == null || potato == null) {
      return badRequest("Missing parameter");
    } else {
    double patateD = Double.parseDouble(patate);
        double potatoD = Double.parseDouble(potato);
        return ok("Json " + json);      
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the curl command I'm using :

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"message": "Guillaume", "potato": "59.34324", "patate": "38.32424"}' http://localhost:9000/api/localfeeds
```

Now, what I want to do is passing multiple Json objects and treat them in Java, which means I want to make this work :

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data '[{"message": "Guillaume", "potato": "59.34324", "patate": "38.32424"}, {"message": "Guillaume2", "potato": "592.34324", "patate": "382.32424"}]' http://localhost:9000/api/localfeeds
```

When reading the answers on Google, all I find is that I should use JSONArray and JSONObject but I get an error in the following code :

```
public static Result addMessage() {
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(json);
if(json == null) {
return badRequest("Expecting Json data");
} else {
for(int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
    String message = jsonobj.findPath("message").getTextValue();
    String patate = jsonobj.findPath("patate").getTextValue();
    String potato = jsonobj.findPath("potato").getTextValue();
    if(message == null || patate == null || potato == null) {
    return badRequest("Missing parameter");
    } else {
        double patateD = Double.parseDouble(patate);
        double potatoD = Double.parseDouble(potato);
        return ok("jsonobj " + jsonobj);    
    }
}
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
-> JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(json);

Comment: Are you sure this class JSONArray really exists? I have Googled a bit and all I can find is hypothetical examples, not an actual class. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: I found it here on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722228/loop-through-a-json-object-in-java

Comment: Weird question. Everyone seems to assume they know what the context is and don't need to provide imports. Very confusing. I suggest you ignore it, and try to find some code from somewhere else, that is _actually for Play 2_.

Comment: I agree, furthermore there is very little documentation on this, and the only one I find is specific to Scala. I thought Java was general and that it's use is not "changed" somehow by Play!. Thanks anyways Robin.

Comment: I don't get why users voted to close this question... anyway all you neeed is just iterating the JsonNode (when you have sure it's always an array of objects: 

`JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        for (JsonNode item : json) {
            play.Logger.info(item.get("message").asText());
        }`

Comment: You sir, are my hero ! Thank you. It works fine ! :)